# Prevent Zsh from quitting if job in background

Tags: zsh, job-control

From `man zsh`, you can see:

> If you [...] try to exit again, the shell will not warn you a second time; the suspended jobs will be terminated, and the running jobs will be sent a `SIGHUP` signal, if the `HUP` option is set.

Is there a way to prevent `zsh` from quitting if a job is in the background?

Comment: Do you want to prevent _any_ kind of termination of the shell, such as from external signalling? Would it be enough to set the `IGNORE_EOF` shell option (prevents exiting on `Ctrl+D` ten times, but does not block `exit` or `logout`)? Do you need to disable the `exit` and `logout` commands?

Comment: There isn't that I'm aware of, at least in the strictest sense of your question. However if what you _actually_ want to accomplish is to ensure that a background job is not interrupted in the event its parent shell exits, it is sufficient to prepend `setsid` to the command and append `disown` to it (after the `&` that sends the process to the background). setsid will place the process into its own session not connected to the calling shell or terminal, so it survives their exits, and disown makes the shell "forget" about it so no HUP signal is sent in the first place.

Comment: From zshall(1): "If  a  job  is  started  with `&|' or `&!', then that job is immediately disowned.", and `!` is less typing than `disown`. But `setsid` still has it's use cases.

Comment: The main issue I encounter is vim not deleting swap files. I don't believe `disown` would solve this problem. What I'm looking for is a way to overwrite `SIGQUIT` to something like `fg || exit`

Comment: So this is _actually_ a question about the Vim editor, not about `zsh`?

Comment: @Kusalananda No the problem is with `zsh`. `vim` is one example, but any command that could run in the background would be affected, like `cp`, or any gui started from the terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code, there doesn't seem to be a direct way of doing this. The check for background jobs is performed in [`zexit`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/zsh-5.8/Src/builtin.c#L5795), which is called when the main zsh process decides to try exiting, whether from `exit`, from `logout`, from an end-of-file or various other circumstances. To cancel the order to exit, `stopmsg` has to be 0. After getting the “you have (running|suspended|stopped) jobs” warning, `stopmsg` is 2. The only way to bring `stopmsg` down is [by preparing to execute a command](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/zsh-5.8/Src/init.c#L210) (from a non-empty command line) *twice*. So if you run `exit`, the next command you enter is not protected from exiting.

I can't think of a way to hook the `exit` builtin (or replace it by a function, etc.) that would allow faking a no-op command afterwards to reset `stopmsg`.

You can disable the `exit` builtin, or replace it by a function that checks whether there are jobs, e.g.

```
function exit {
  emulate -L zsh
  setopt extended_glob
  if [[ -n ${jobstates[(r)s*]} ]]; then
    echo "you have suspended jobs"
    return 1
  fi
  if [[ -n ${jobstates[(r)^done:*]} ]]; then
    echo "you have running jobs"
    return 1
  fi
  builtin exit "$@"
}
```

But this only takes care of `exit`, not of other methods.

For end of file, you can `setopt ignore_eof`.