# Is there a way to not exit a shell if jobs are stopped/suspended?

Tags: shell, zsh, logout

If one types `exit` and a job is stopped/suspended, the shell will print a warning message instead of exiting.

```
1: some_command &
[1] 4018347
2: exit
zsh: you have suspended jobs.
```

But if one types `exit` again, the shell will exit.

```
3: exit
<session terminates>
```

Is there a way to prevent this, and **never** exit if there are stopped/suspended jobs?

```
3: exit
zsh: you have suspended jobs.
4: exit
zsh: you have suspended jobs.
5: exit
zsh: you have suspended jobs.
6: exit
zsh: you have suspended jobs.
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/724093/414186)

Comment: Is this a frequent problem or rather specific jobs that might be handled better using `nohup`?

Comment: @FelixJN No it's not frequent.  It's usually some vi job that i suspended and then forgot about.